# Activeresource custom method :id specification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeresource

I need/want to put to a custom method with activeresource

```
myresource.put(:go_crazy, {:go => "go", :crazy => "crazy"})
```

Which goes to on the server where the resource is

```
/myresource/:id(pretend is the integer 1)/go_crazy?go=go%crazy=crazy
```

Only, I need to specify that the :id is something else e.g. 'myresource.crazy_key'

I've actually figured out another way to do this as a workaround, but I can't seem to get at what I need to do to specify the id as something else, if I can do this at all.

Answer (score 2):

In your "Resource" model, override the `to_param` method

```
def to_param
    crazy_key.to_s
end
```

Comment: It is already there from previous, I use that key as an id with AR, BUT not as to_s

Answer (score 1):

I assume you wanted to use something else instead of :id in URL. Then you must define attribute which will act as primary key in your active resource class:

```
class FooBar < ActiveResource::Base
    self.site="http://host/root/"
    self.primary_key = :name
end
```

then

```
FooBar.find('XYZ').get(:subfoo)
```

will request

```
http://host/root/foo_bar/XYZ/subfoo
```